Probability of a Chain of Inequalities
Let $y_{i}, a_{i}>0$ for all $i =1,2,…,n$. Suppose $F$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, i.e., $F(u) = u, \ \forall u \in [0,1]$ and that $Y_{i} \sim F^{a_{i}}$, i.e., $P(Y_i \leq u)$ = $u^{a_i}, \ \forall u \in [0,1]$. Assuming $Y_i$'s are independent, calculate the probability:
$$P(Y_{1}<…<Y_{n})=\int_{0<y_{1}<…<y_{n}<1}\prod_{i=1}^{n}dy_{i}^{a_{i}}$$
Things attempted: I tried to find an expression in the case of $n=2$ and found that the integral then equals $\frac{a_{1}a_{2}}{a_{1}a_{2}+a_{2}}$. I feel like this can be further generalised to: $$\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}}$$
and tried showing this by induction, but had no success.

When you say $F$ is the uniform distribution, you mean $F(x)=\min(\max(x,0),1)$ is the cdf of the $\text{Unif}(0,1)$ distribution, correct? And when you say $Y_i\sim F^{a_i}$, you mean, for $y\in \mathbb R$, that $P(Y_i<y)=(F(y))^{a_i}$?

@MikeEarnest yes.

Should it be the following? $$\prod_{i=2}^n \frac{a_i}{\sum_{j=1}^i a_j}$$

By observing the first examples:
$$\begin{aligned}
P(Y_1<x)&=x^{a_1}\\
\implies P(Y_1<Y_2)&=E[P(Y_1<y_2)|_{y_2=Y_2}]=a_2\int_0^1y_2^{a_1+a_2-1}dy_2=\frac{a_2}{a_1+a_2}\\
P(Y_1<Y_2<x)&=E[P(Y_1<y_2<x)]|_{y_2=Y_2}]=a_2\int_0^xy_2^{a_1+a_2-1}dy_2=\frac{a_2}{a_1+a_2}x^{a_1+a_2}\\
\implies P(Y_1<Y_2<Y_3)&=E[P(Y_1<Y_2<y_3)]|_{y_3=Y_3}]=\frac{a_3a_2}{a_1+a_2}\int_0^1{y_3}^{a_1+a_2+a_3-1}dy_3\\
&=\frac{a_3a_2}{(a_1+a_2)(a_1+a_2+a_3)}\\
P(Y_1<Y_2<Y_3<x)&=E[P(Y_1<Y_2<y_3<x)]|_{y_3=Y_3}]=\frac{a_3a_2}{a_1+a_2}\int_0^x{y_3}^{a_1+a_2+a_3-1}dy_3\\
&=\frac{a_3a_2}{(a_1+a_2)(a_1+a_2+a_3)}x^{a_1+a_2+a_3}\\
&(...)
\end{aligned}$$
The pattern has emerged. Suppose that
$$P(Y_1<...<Y_n<x)=\frac{\prod_{2\leq k \leq n}a_k}{\prod_{2\leq k \leq n}(a_1+...+a_k)}x^{a_1+...+a_n}$$
Then
$$\begin{aligned}P(Y_1<...<Y_n<Y_{n+1}<x)&=E[P(Y_1<...<Y_n<y_{n+1}<x)]|_{y_{n+1}=Y_{n+1}}]\\
&=\frac{\prod_{2\leq k \leq n}a_k}{\prod_{2\leq k \leq n}(a_1+...+a_k)}a_{n+1}\int_0^x{y_{n+1}}^{a_1+...+a_n+a_{n+1}-1}dy_{n+1}\\
&=\frac{\prod_{2\leq k \leq n+1}a_k}{\prod_{2\leq k \leq n+1}(a_1+...+a_k)}x^{a_1+...+a_n+a_{n+1}}\end{aligned}$$
and so we conclude:
$$\begin{aligned}P(Y_1<...<Y_n)&=E[P(Y_1<...<Y_{n-1}<y_n)|_{y_n=Y_n}]\\
&=\frac{\prod_{2\leq k \leq n-1}a_k}{\prod_{2\leq k \leq n-1}(a_1+...+a_k)}a_n\int_0^1{y_n}^{a_1+...+a_{n-1}+a_n-1}dy_{n}\\
&=\frac{\prod_{2\leq k \leq n}a_k}{\prod_{2\leq k \leq n}(a_1+...+a_k)}
\end{aligned}$$
